# cut() a variable with missing values

Tags: r, na

What's a good way to [`cut()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.0/topics/cut) 
a quantiative variable into levels, including a final level dedicated to NAs?

I'd prefer something like the `.missing` parameter that tidyverse functions commonly offer
(*e.g.*, [`dplyr::recode()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/recode.html) & [`dplyr::if_else()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/if_else.html)).

If the input is `w` and this hypothetical function is named `cut_with_nas`, then the following code

```
w <- c(0L, NA_integer_, 22:25, NA_integer_, 40)
cut_with_nas(w, breaks=2)
```

would produce this desired output:

```
[1] (-0.04,20] Unknown    (20,40]    (20,40]    (20,40]    (20,40]    Unknown    (20,40]   
Levels: (-0.04,20] (20,40] Unknown
```

I'm posting a function below that accomplishes this, but I was hoping there's a more concise solution, or at least a tested function already existing in a package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cut_with_nas   <- function( x, breaks, labels=NULL, .missing="Unknown" ) {
  y <- cut(x, breaks, labels) #, include.lowest = T, right=F)
  y <- addNA(y)
  levels(y)[is.na(levels(y))] <- .missing
  return( y )
}
```

The majority of this function steals heavily from a [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31704710/1082435) by @akrun three years ago.
(And a little from [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31010248/1082435) too.)

Comment: after four months, there hasn't been another proposal.  I'll mark this my own response as an answer, but would be happy to switch the checkmark for a better answer.